# Unable to get left outer join result in mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
  SELECT 
        BB.NAME BranchName,
        VI.NAME Village,
        COUNT(BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER) 'No.Of Accounts',
        SUM(BAC.CURRENTBALANCE) SumOfAmount,
        SUM(CASE
            WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS CreditTotal,
        SUM(CASE
            WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS DebitTotal,
        SUM(CASE
            WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount
            WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN - 1 * amount
            ELSE 0
        END) AS CurrentBalance
    FROM
        CUSTOMER CU,
        APPLICANT AP,
        ADDRESS AD,
        VILLAGE VI,
        BANKBRANCH BB,
        BANKACCOUNT BAC
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        accounttransaction ACT ON BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER = ACT.BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER
            AND ACT.TRANDATE <= '2013-03-21'
            AND BAC.ACCOUNTOPENINGDATE < '2013-03-21'
            AND ACT.BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER IS NOT NULL
    WHERE
        CU.CODE = AP.CUSTOMER_CODE
            AND BAC.ENTITY = 'CUSTOMER'
            AND BAC.ENTITYCODE = CU.CODE
            AND AD.ENTITY = 'APPLICANT'
            AND AD.ENTITYCODE = AP.CODE
            AND AD.VILLAGE_CODE = VI.CODE
            AND AD.STATE_CODE = VI.STATE_CODE
            AND AD.DISTRICT_CODE = VI.DISTRICT_CODE
            AND AD.BLOCK_CODE = VI.BLOCK_CODE
            AND AD.PANCHAYAT_CODE = VI.PANCHAYAT_CODE
            AND CU.BANKBRANCH_CODE = BB.CODE
            AND BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER IS NOT NULL
            AND ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY BB.NAME , VI.NAME;
```

Here is my information
    I have two tables bankaccount and accountransactions table 
    If account is created it will go to bankaccount table and if any transaction is done so respective account number record in accounttrasactiosns table however I want to display the count of total account numbers respective to the branch which the account number existed in bankaccount and it is may or may not available in accounttransactions table.

Comment: Ok now we know what you want. And what is the problem currently? Besides can you simplify that big query to the actual problem? And a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would help too.

Comment: ...or at least format it nicely?

Comment: I have formatted please look into this

Comment: How is MySQL Workbench related to this? Does it work outside of Workbench? Why are you mixing two join syntaxes? Oh, wait, I already [asked you that last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192911/mysql-query-taking-more-time-to-execute). :)

Comment: Don't mix implicit (comma-) and explicit join styles (unless you really know what you're doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem you have is that you are not getting results for accounts that do not have data in your `accounttransaction` table, even though you are using a `LEFT JOIN`.  If that is true, the reason is because your join condition includes `AND ACT.BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER IS NOT NULL`, which defeats the `LEFT JOIN`.  You also have two conditions in your `WHERE` clause that I bet should not be there.

You should learn to use **explicit join** syntax in your coding.  Your code will be much clearer if you do that; it separates the join conditions from the `WHERE` clause, which does a very different thing.  I took a stab at re-writing your query as an illustration:

```
SELECT
    BB.NAME BranchName,
    VI.NAME Village,
    COUNT(BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER) 'No.Of Accounts',
    SUM(BAC.CURRENTBALANCE) SumOfAmount,
    SUM(ACT.CurrentBalance) CurrentBalance,
    SUM(ACT.DebitTotal) DebitTotal,
    SUM(ACT.CreditTotal) CreditTotal

FROM   CUSTOMER CU

JOIN   APPLICANT AP
ON     AP.CUSTOMER_CODE = CU.CODE

JOIN   ADDRESS AD
ON     AD.ENTITYCODE = AP.CODE

JOIN   VILLAGE VI
ON     VI.CODE           = AD.VILLAGE_CODE
   AND VI.STATE_CODE     = AD.STATE_CODE
   AND VI.DISTRICT_CODE  = AD.DISTRICT_CODE
   AND VI.BLOCK_CODE     = AD.BLOCK_CODE
   AND VI.PANCHAYAT_CODE = AD.PANCHAYAT_CODE

JOIN   BANKBRANCH BB
ON     BB.CODE = CU.BANKBRANCH_CODE

JOIN   BANKACCOUNT BAC
ON     BAC.ENTITYCODE = CU.CODE

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER,
          SUM(CASE
             WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount
             ELSE 0
             END) AS CreditTotal,
          SUM(CASE
             WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN amount
             ELSE 0
             END) AS DebitTotal,
          SUM(CASE
             WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount
             WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN - 1 * amount
             ELSE 0
             END) AS CurrentBalance
   FROM    accounttransaction
   WHERE   TRANDATE <= '2013-03-21'
   GROUP BY BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER
   ) ACT

ON     ACT.BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER = BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER
   AND BAC.ACCOUNTOPENINGDATE < '2013-03-21'

WHERE  BAC.ENTITY = 'CUSTOMER'
   AND AD.ENTITY = 'APPLICANT'

GROUP BY BB.NAME , VI.NAME;
```

I removed this line from the `LEFT JOIN` condition

```
AND ACT.BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER IS NOT NULL
```

And I removed these two lines from the WHERE clause

```
AND BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER IS NOT NULL
AND ACT.TRANSACTIONTYPE IS NOT NULL
```

If that does not solve your problem, please revise your question to explain further.

**UPDATE:** Based on comments, the query is revised to calculate the debit, credit, and current balance by account using a derived table.

Also note the placement of the `BAC.ACCOUNTOPENINGDATE < '2013-03-21'` condition on left join.  As written, this will return all accounts regardless of the opening date.  If you want to only show accounts that were opened before that date, this condition should be moved to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Here in one branch from the BANKBRANCK table having 263 accounts when I executed the above query using Left outer join the count is increasing to 293 which is wrong because only accounts opened under that branch is 263 the result is 293 which is wrong. If I remove the Left outer join then my result is 263 for one branch when I include the Left out join then count is increasing to 293, please help me where is the problem

Comment: Are the columns `transactiontype` and `amount` coming from your `accounttransaction` table?  If so, you may need to use a "derived table" to get the correct result.  Confirm and I'll update the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: yes, transactiontype and amount are from accounttransaction table only

Comment: still I didn't get the total number of accounts from bankbranch still the number is 293 only instead of 263

Comment: Sorry I cannot help more; I guess your data is more complicated than I can tell.  Stack Overflow isn't a very good place to troubleshooting complex problems.