# Unable to get exact result using left outer join in mysql banking system?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
        SELECT
                    BB.NAME BranchName,
                    VI.NAME Village,
                    COUNT(BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER) 'No.Of Accounts',
                    SUM(BAC.CURRENTBALANCE) SumOfAmount,
                    SUM(CASE
                        WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS CreditTotal,
                    SUM(CASE
                        WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN amount
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS DebitTotal,
                    SUM(CASE
                        WHEN transactiontype = 'C' THEN amount
                        WHEN transactiontype = 'D' THEN - 1 * amount
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS CurrentBalance

                FROM   CUSTOMER CU

                JOIN   APPLICANT AP
                ON     AP.CUSTOMER_CODE = CU.CODE

                JOIN   ADDRESS AD
                ON     AD.ENTITYCODE = AP.CODE

                JOIN   VILLAGE VI
                ON     VI.CODE           = AD.VILLAGE_CODE
                   AND VI.STATE_CODE     = AD.STATE_CODE
                   AND VI.DISTRICT_CODE  = AD.DISTRICT_CODE
                   AND VI.BLOCK_CODE     = AD.BLOCK_CODE
                   AND VI.PANCHAYAT_CODE = AD.PANCHAYAT_CODE

                JOIN   BANKBRANCH BB
                ON     BB.CODE = CU.BANKBRANCH_CODE

                JOIN   BANKACCOUNT BAC
                ON     BAC.ENTITYCODE = CU.CODE

                LEFT OUTER JOIN accounttransaction ACT 
                ON ACT.BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER= BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER
                   AND ACT.TRANDATE <= '2013-07-01'
                   AND BAC.ACCOUNTOPENINGDATE < '2013-07-01'

                WHERE  BAC.ENTITY = 'CUSTOMER'
                   AND AD.ENTITY = 'APPLICANT'

                GROUP BY BB.NAME,VI.NAME;
```

Here in one branch from the BANKBRANCK table having 263 accounts when I executed the above query using Left outer join the count is increasing to 293 which is wrong because only accounts opened under that branch is 263 the result is 293 which is wrong.
    If I remove the Left outer join then my result is 263 for one branch when I include the Left out join then count is increasing to 293, please help me where is the problem

```
   This is the continuous for the below question

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277899/unable-to-get-left-outer-join-result-in-mysql-query/17279769#17279769
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 0):

This Part

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounttransaction ACT 
            ON ACT.BANKACCOUNT_CBSACCOUNTNUMBER= BAC.CBSACCOUNTNUMBER
               AND ACT.TRANDATE <= '2013-07-01'
               AND BAC.ACCOUNTOPENINGDATE < '2013-07-01'
```

Allows for more than 1 row on the accounttransaction table to be returned, which will allow the row count to increase from 263 to 293. Left Join does not implicitly limit the joined data to only one match.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do, you are left joining, but not visibly using anything from the table you join to (but I suspect you are implicitly using it thru just missing table aliases on fields.) What is the purpose of the join?

Comment: I want the number of accounts branch wise,village wise along with account transaction date (from transaction table) and account open date (from bankbranch table)

Comment: And there is the problem - which account transaction date? Accounts will surely have multiple transactions which means you need to group of them and make a decision, first, last etc

Comment: I am mentioning the ACT.TRANDATE <= '2013-03-31' what are the account transactions done till '2013-03-31' from the date of account open